# How to provide access in bulk

Tags: profile, object, access, userrecordaccess

I have created a custom object with over 50 custom fields but only system administrators have access to all the fields now is there any way I can provide the access to other profiles at once

I can edit each field and then select the profile but is there any other way where I provide access at once.

Comment: you can use ANT, for example, and change all Profiles.-> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool like https://profilepowertools.com/ which gives an easy UI to mass update FLS
Other tools exist also